# The Fourier transform of $ f(x)=xe^{{-x}^2} $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I know how to calculate the Fourier Transform using the main formula and integrals calculations. But i want to calculate the Fourier Transform of

$ f(x)=xe^{{-x}^2} $

using the following formula :

for  $f(x)=e^{{-ax}^2} (a>0)    $ then $ \mathbb{F}(f)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}} e^{{{-\omega}^2}/4a}  $

How can i do that?

Note: Should I also use the rule of $ \mathbb{F}\{f'(x)\}=i\omega\mathbb{F} \{f(x)\}  $ ?

Comment: you almost have it

Comment: @tired Cannot find a way to use the given formula so as to calculate my own problem.

Comment: $(e^{-x^2})'=2 x e^{-x^2}$

so you calculate the FT of a derivative of a Gaussian

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just How can we get from $ \mathbb{F}(xe^{{-x}^{2}} )   $ to $ \mathbb{F}\{(-1/2(e^{{-x}^{2}} )' \}  $ . I don't seem to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the derivative formula of the Fourier transform.

> Assume $\mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}=F(\omega)$. then
>   $$\mathcal{F}\{f'(x)\}=(i\omega)F(w)$$

For $f(x)=e^{-ax^2}$ and $F(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}} e^{{{-\omega}^2}/4a}$ we have $f'(x)=(-2ax)e^{-ax^2}$ . Hence, $$\mathcal{F}\{(-2ax)e^{-ax^2}\}=\frac{i\omega}{\sqrt{2a}} e^{{{-\omega}^2}/4a}$$
Therefore, choosing $a=1$ and simplifying we have

$$\boxed{\mathcal{F}\{xe^{-x^2}\}=\frac{i\omega}{-2\sqrt{2}} e^{{{-\omega}^2}/4}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\mathcal{F}(xe^{-x^2} )(\omega)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xe^{-x^2}e^{-i\omega x} dx =$

$\displaystyle=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{2} e^{-x^2}e^{-i\omega x}\right)|_{-\infty}^{+\infty} -\frac{i\omega}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{-i\omega x} dx$

$\displaystyle=0-\frac{i\omega}{2}\mathcal{F}(e^{-x^2})(\omega)=-\frac{i\omega}{2\sqrt{2}} e^{-\omega^2/4} $

Comment: Thanks for your help. I notice that is the way of doing the main formula and integrals. i reckon there is a shorter way of $ \mathbb{F}(xe^{{-x}^{2}} )$ to $\mathbb{F}\{(-1/2(e^{{-x}^{2}} )' \}$. but i cant figure out How we can get from $ \mathbb{F}(xe^{{-x}^{2}} )$ to $\mathbb{F}\{(-1/2(e^{{-x}^{2}} )' \}$ . I don't seem to get it.

Comment: $\mathcal{F}(xe^{-x^2} )(\omega)$ and $\mathcal{F}(-\frac{1}{2}(e^{-x^2})')(\omega)$ are equal because of  $xe^{-x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}(e^{-x^2})'$ . Use $\mathcal{F}(-\frac{1}{2}(e^{-x^2})')(\omega)=-\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{F}((e^{-x^2})')(\omega)$ and $\mathcal{F}((e^{-x^2})')(\omega)=i\omega\mathcal{F}(e^{-x^2})(\omega)$ .